# how can I make a loading for web browser in android

Tags: android

how can I make loading dialog for web browser in android?
application should load url and show loading dialog. and when web browser load url compeletly close the loading dialog.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android webview client activity indicator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310784/android-webview-client-activity-indicator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android showing progress bar for webview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309227/android-showing-progress-bar-for-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `WebView` and make it extends a custom `WebViewClient`

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Your custom `WebViewClient` will let you know when the page has started loading and when the page has finished loading. Simply show the `ProgressBar` while the page is loading and hide upon its finished loading.

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```